# Sincronizar php e ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou fazendo um select em php usando uma váriavel que vem do ajax, o problema é que o php está tentando fazer a consulta antes de receber o valor ajax, isso gera um erro na página e a rotina é quebrada no meio,

SEGUE O LOG DE ERRO DO CONSOLE:

```
<div class='modal fade' id='modalVisualizarComponentes' tabindex='-1'     role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModal'>
<div class='modal-dialog modal-lg' role='document' style='height:80% !important; width:100% !important;'>
<div class='modal-content'><div class='modal-header'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button><h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'>Componentes</h4></div>
<div class='modal-body'><table class='table table-striped'><tr><th>Sequencial</th><th>Código</th><th>Nome</th><th>Entrada</th><th>Saída</th><th>Quantidade F</th><th>Quantidade M</th><th>Quantidade G</th><th>Quantidade GG</th><th>Total</th><tbody><br />
```

// AQUI É AONDE PRECISO FAZER A CONSULTA POREM O CAMPO QUE PRECISO ESTA LÁ EM BAIXO.

**Warning**:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Manutencao\administrador.php** on line **265**
    
    Sair

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js">                 </script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validaCampoAparelho()
{
  if (document.aparelho.labelAparelho.value=="")
  {
    alert("O campo aparelho está em branco!!");
    return;
  }
}
$("#visualizarAparelhos").submit(function (e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    var dados = $("#visualizarAparelhos").serialize();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST", 
          url: "administrador.php",
          data: {selectComponentes: dados}
        }).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            //$("#modalVisualizarComponentes").show();
        });
    return false;
    });
```

// ESSA É A INFORMAÇÃO QUE EU PRECISO PARA FAZER A CONSULTA

```
selectComponentes=9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

é possível corrigir o erro com um safecheck no teu php:

```
if ($_POST['selectComponentes']) {
  //.. faz a consulta
}
```

porém, note que o ideal é que o ajax peça para **outro arquivo** e não para o mesmo em que ele está.

Comment: Eu mudei totalmente a estrutura do sistema para resolver o problema, porem acredito que com o seu código teria funcionado, então vou marcar a questão como respondida, para ajudar outras pessoas.